# SmartGWT - can't click into items into windows modal

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I have one problem using `Window` with `setIsModal(true)`.

I have this code:

```
@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {

    Button tester = new Button("Tester");

    tester.addClickHandler(new com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            final com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Window win = new com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Window();
            win.setTitle("Ventana Tester");
            win.setWidth(900);
            win.setHeight(600);
            win.setIsModal(true);
            win.setShowModalMask(true);
            win.centerInPage();
            win.setMinimized(false);

            win.addCloseClickHandler(new CloseClickHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onCloseClick(CloseClientEvent event) {
                    win.destroy();
                }
            });


            PlanBoard pb = new PlanBoard();
            win.addItem(pb);

            win.show();

        }
    });

    vlPrincipal.addMember(tester);

    RootPanel.get("main").add(vlPrincipal);
}
```

and this is PlanBoard class:

```
public class PlanBoard extends VLayout{


private CaptionPanel contentDetallePlan =  new CaptionPanel("DETALLES DEL PLAN");
private CaptionPanel contentAtributosPlan =  new CaptionPanel("ATRIBUTOS DE PLAN");
private CaptionPanel contentSeccionesPlan =  new CaptionPanel("SECCIONES");

public PlanBoard(){

    contentDetallePlan.setStyleName("estiloCaptionPanel");
    contentAtributosPlan.setStyleName("estiloCaptionPanel");

    addMember(contentDetallePlan);
    addMember(contentAtributosPlan);
    addMember(contentSeccionesPlan);


    preparaDetallePlan();
    preparaAtributosPlan();
}


private void preparaDetallePlan(){

    VLayout contenedorSeccion = new VLayout();

    FlexTable table1 = new FlexTable();
    FlexTable table2 = new FlexTable();
    FlexTable table3 = new FlexTable();

    Label np = new Label("Nombre de Plan:");
    Label npText = new Label("Plan B");

    Label tc = new Label("Tipo de Carta:");
    DynamicForm tcForm = new DynamicForm();
    ComboBoxItem tcBox =  new ComboBoxItem();
    tcBox.setWidth(250);
    tcBox.setShowTitle(false);
    tcForm.setItems(tcBox);

    Label pr = new Label("Periodo:");
    DynamicForm prForm = new DynamicForm();
    ComboBoxItem prBox =  new ComboBoxItem();
    prBox.setWidth(150);
    prBox.setShowTitle(false);
    prForm.setItems(prBox);


    Label dp = new Label("Descripcion:");
    DynamicForm dpForm = new DynamicForm();
    TextAreaItem dpText =  new TextAreaItem();
    dpText.setShowTitle(false);
    dpText.setWidth(600);
    dpForm.setItems(dpText);



    table1.setWidget(0, 0, np);
    table1.setWidget(0, 1, npText);

    table2.setWidget(0, 0, tc);
    table2.setWidget(0, 1, tcForm);
    table2.setWidget(0, 2, pr);
    table2.setWidget(0, 3, prForm);

    table3.setWidget(0, 1, dp);
    table3.setWidget(1, 1, dpForm);

    contenedorSeccion.addMember(table1);
    contenedorSeccion.addMember(table2);
    contenedorSeccion.addMember(table3);

    contentDetallePlan.add(contenedorSeccion);


}

private void preparaAtributosPlan(){

    VLayout contenedorSeccion = new VLayout(); 

    FlexTable table1 = new FlexTable();

    Label fe = new Label("Firma Electornica:");
    CheckboxItem feCheck = new CheckboxItem();
    DateItem feFechaIni = new DateItem();
    DateItem feFechaFin = new DateItem();

    feFechaIni.setUseTextField(true);

    feCheck.setShowTitle(false);

    DynamicForm feForm = new DynamicForm();
    feForm.setItems(feCheck,feFechaIni,feFechaFin);

    table1.setWidget(0, 0, fe);
    table1.setWidget(0, 1, feForm);

    contenedorSeccion.addMember(table1);

    contentAtributosPlan.add(contenedorSeccion);


}
```

The problem is when I try to click on `CheckBoxItem` or `DateItem`, I can't edit them, but when I don't use `setIsModal(true)`, it works fine.

I don't know how to set the `Window` to `modal(true)`, and have those items working on that window.

Comment: What is `vlPrincipal` in your EntryPoint class? You don't declare it anywhere.  Also, since you are mixing SmartGWT and GWT components, includes are necessary to know which library you are using for specific components available in both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code cleaned (a little bit) and improved so that what you want to achieve (which is the modal window with selectable/actionable controls):

**PlanBoard.java**

```
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.DynamicForm;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.CheckboxItem;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.ComboBoxItem;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.DateItem;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.StaticTextItem;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.TextAreaItem;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.layout.VLayout;

public class PlanBoard extends VLayout {

    public PlanBoard(){
        preparaDetallePlan();
        preparaAtributosPlan();
        preparaSecciones();
    }


    private void preparaDetallePlan(){
        StaticTextItem np = new StaticTextItem("id2", "Nombre de Plan:");
        StaticTextItem npText = new StaticTextItem("id2", "Plan B");

        ComboBoxItem tcBox =  new ComboBoxItem();
        tcBox.setTitle("Tipo de Carta");
        tcBox.setWidth(250);

        ComboBoxItem prBox =  new ComboBoxItem();
        tcBox.setTitle("Periodo");
        prBox.setWidth(150);

        StaticTextItem dp = new StaticTextItem("id3", "Descripcion:");

        TextAreaItem dpText =  new TextAreaItem();
        dpText.setShowTitle(false);
        dpText.setWidth(600);
        dpText.setStartRow(true);
        dpText.setEndRow(true);
        dpText.setColSpan(2);

        DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();
        form.setItems(np, npText, tcBox, prBox, dp, dpText);
        form.setIsGroup(true);
        form.setGroupTitle("DETALLES DE PLAN");

        addMember(form);
    }

    private void preparaAtributosPlan(){
        StaticTextItem fe = new StaticTextItem("id4", "Firma Electornica:");
        CheckboxItem feCheck = new CheckboxItem();
        feCheck.setShowTitle(false);

        DateItem feFechaIni = new DateItem();
        DateItem feFechaFin = new DateItem();
        feFechaIni.setUseTextField(true);

        DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();
        form.setItems(fe, feCheck, feFechaIni, feFechaFin);
        form.setIsGroup(true);
        form.setGroupTitle("ATRIBUTOS DE PLAN");

        addMember(form);
    }

    private void preparaSecciones(){
        DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();
        form.setIsGroup(true);
        form.setGroupTitle("SECCIONES");
        addMember(form);
    }
}
```

**TestCases.java** (rename to your EntryPoint class name, which you don't specify):

```
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.IButton;  
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Window;  
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.ClickEvent;  
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.ClickHandler;  
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.CloseClickEvent;  
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.CloseClickHandler;  
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.layout.VLayout; 

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;

public class TestCases implements EntryPoint {  

    public void onModuleLoad() {  

         IButton tester = new IButton("Tester");
         tester.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                final Window win = new Window();
                win.setTitle("Ventana Tester");
                win.setWidth(900);
                win.setHeight(600);
                win.setIsModal(true);
                win.setShowModalMask(true);
                win.centerInPage();
                win.setMinimized(false);

                win.addCloseClickHandler(new CloseClickHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCloseClick(CloseClickEvent event) {
                        win.destroy();
                    }
                });

                PlanBoard pb = new PlanBoard();
                win.addItem(pb);
                win.show();
            }
        });

        VLayout vlPrincipal = new VLayout();
        vlPrincipal.addMember(tester);
        vlPrincipal.draw();
    }  
}
```

Some notes:

- **Don't mix GWT and SmartGWT widgets unless absolutely necessary and only when you really know what you are doing** (because it will generated unexpected results, as the one you are experiencing). In your case, the mixing is unnecessary!!
- You can add the titles to the different controls you are using, and they will display as labels. You can specify if the title label appears above or to one side, per control.
- Take a look at [this](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#form_controls_various) SmartGWT demo to learn how to configure and use the different types of `DynamicForm` controls. Many of the things you were trying to do, you were doing more difficult than necessary.
- On the "stylistic" aspect, don't write your code using Spanglish. I speak Spanish, so I understand, but it limits a lot the feedback you get, because your code is so much more difficult to understand. Use English (at least for code you intend to post in SO).

Comment: Thanks Carlos, the problem was that by putting these items in the CaptionPanel were not working.

And sorry for my Tarzan english ;D

Comment: It's ok. Just keep it in mind for future posts (and I think it's also a good general rule: code in English... you never know when you are going to need help from someone that doesn't speaks Spanish).